# CKEditor icons vertical

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

Live view : http://wallingfordrodandgunclub.org/newsite/members/forum/reply.php

When I remove anything extra from the page it shows up fine. It's not the small space either, I've tested putting it out of the div that it's in and let it take up the whole page on the bottom. Could it be that my CSS style is interfering with it?

This is the form I have it in.

```
<FORM METHOD="post" ACTION= "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?board=<?php echo $boardID ?>">
    <textarea name="editor1">
    <?php
    echo $postContent;
    ?>
    </textarea>
    <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
    </script>
    <input TYPE="submit" NAME="submit" VALUE="Post"> <input TYPE="submit" NAME="preview" VALUE="Preview"> 
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
body a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  clear: both;
}
```

from main.css line 14. CKEditor must float those link side by side, and clear:both clears float on every link on the entire page. It's usually not a good idea to apply a rule so generally, better to give those links a class, and apply it to them specifically.

**Update:**

This is from your css. Fire up chrome or safari, right click on any link on the page, choose inspect element, then from the styles panel on the right uncheck the box that says "clear:both" under "body a", and everything snaps back into place.

> I was trying to remove blue links on ie from around my button links. Is there another way of doing that?

The line "text-decoration: none;" will remove things like blue lines around links, and you can keep that if you want. The only line presently causing you problems is "clear:both", so you could change the above to:

```
body a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

I would generally prefer to give all of the buttons on my page a class like "menu-button", then change the css to:

```
a.menu-button{
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  clear: both;
}
```

or nest all of my buttons within a class like "menu", then change the css to:

```
.menu a
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  clear: both;
}
```

That way only those specific elements are being affected, not every link on the page.

Comment: I'm not at my computer right now, but this is from my CSS? If it is I was trying to remove blue links on ie from around my button links. Is there another way of doing that?

Comment: I only needed to remove the outline within my .activitybutton class. After doing that and removing body a{} everything worked fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: Oh I never saw your update until now. That was very informative, thanks for the tip.